# Use coordinates from Geotools geometry-object to send request to Webserver

Tags: coordinates, geotools, web-service

I have a polygon as a Geotools Geometry Object.

No I want to use the coordinates of the polygon to send a request to a webserver.
The webserver demands the coordinates to be in the following format (all coordinates separated by commas):

```
http://....&coordinates=21.205285624773502,62.75338836781611,21.241110826971651,62.75063258303164,21.231190001747548,....
```

Is there a name for that kind of format and has Geotools a method to convert it directly to it?

The only way I see right now would be to convert it to a String, which gives me a WKT-format and then using String methods to get it to the right format. I thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
Coordinate[] coords = geometry.getCoordinates();
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
out.append("coordinates=");
boolean start = true;
for(Coordinate c: coords) {
  if(!start){
      out.append(",");
  }else{
      start=false;
  }
  out.append(c.x+","+c.y);
}
```